# Is it possible to have a data delay between nodes in distributed mode Infinispan?

Tags: caching, distributed-computing, infinispan, distributed-caching, infinispan-9

With Infinispan v9, my app uses a distributed async cache mode where number of cluster-wide data replicas is 3.

Let's say data owner/replica of cache **entry 123** is in **Nodes A, B, C**.

With this, I have two questions (assuming they were not caused by network issues)

- If **Node C** enquires for **entry 123**, is it possible that Node C will find the entry missing due to replication delay?
- If **Node D** enquires for **entry 123**, is it possible that Node D will find the entry missing due to some sort of lag?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming node `A` as primary owner of *entry 123* (each key has 1 primary owner and `N-1` backup owners, where `N` is the number of replicas)

- Yes, node `C` can read stale values due to replication lag.
- If you have some lag, yes it can happen. When a read happens in a non-owner node (like `D`), it first tries to fetch the value from the primary owner (node `A`). If `A` doesn't reply in time, then it goes to the next owner (node `B`) and so one.

Now, if `A` replies in time, it won't read the stale the value. Otherwise, it may read the stale value from node `B` or `C`

You have this information (and more) in the [documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#distribution-configuring).